# conevert multidimensional array from multiple tables into single json array value using php

Tags: php, arrays, json, mysqli

In my php script trying to execute the data from multiple tables in single json file with multidimensional array.

So i will explain with my code:

```
if($data){    
            $sql="select * from en_providers where providerEmailAddress='".$email."' and providerPW='".$password."'";
            $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql) or die("Error in Selecting " . mysqli_error($connection));
            if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
                 $resultArray = array();
             while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            $providerID = $row['providerID'];
            $resultArray['providers'] = $row; 

            $sql1="select * from en_venues where providerID = $providerID ";
            $result1 = mysqli_query($con,$sql1) or die("Error in Selecting " . mysqli_error($connection));
             $i=0;
        while ($row1['venue'][] = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result1)){
        echo $venueID=$row1['venue'][$i++]['venueID'];
        $resultArray['venues'] = $row1; 


            $sql2 = "select * from en_schedules as e ,en_persons as p where e.venueID = '".$venueID."'";
            $result2 = mysqli_query($con,$sql2) or die("Error in Selecting " . mysqli_error($con));
            while ($row2['Persons'][] = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2)){
                $resultArray['Persons'] = $row2; 
            }  
}
}
echo json_encode($resultArray);
}
```

Ouput getting like

```
{
"providers": {
             "providerID": "1",
             "providerEmailAddress": "info@gdtennis.co.uk",
             "providerPW": "xxx",
             "providerName": "GDT Tennis ",
             "providerActive": "yes",
             "providerFeatured": "no",
           },
"venues": {
     "venue": {
           "venueID": "8",
           "providerID": "1",
           "venueActive": "yes",
           "venueName": "Wargrave LTC ",
              }
 }
"Persons": {
"Persons": [
  {
"scheduleID": "1",
"venueID": "151",
"scheduleTitle": "Mini Tennis Red ",
"scheduleDay": "Monday",
},
{
"scheduleID": "1",
"venueID": "151",
"scheduleTitle": "Mini Tennis yellow ",
"scheduleDay": "Monday",
},
{
"scheduleID": "1",
"venueID": "152",
"scheduleTitle": "Mini Tennis orange ",
"scheduleDay": "sunday",
}
],
}
}
```

In the venues array i am getting only one array actuellly it has 7 array values. but its getting only one i dont know why like this.

please help me to solve the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you just made one mistake just change $row1['venue'] to $row1['venue'][]

```
 $i=0;
  while ($row1['venue'][] = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result1)){    
    $venueID=$row1['venue'][$i++]['venueID'];
    }
```

Comment: getting error like <b>Notice</b>: Undefined index: venueID

Comment: Resoponse getting empty bro @Arun

Comment: $venueID value printing 1234567

Comment: what is your $venueID contains ? print_r($venueID) and see

Comment: sorry bro values are correct but its getting empty response for final result

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144546/discussion-between-saiibitta-and-arun-kumaresh).

Comment: bro have a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44062085/how-to-insert-multiple-objects-in-json-array-values-into-different-tables-and-ro

Comment: $resultArray['venues'][$k++]['venueIDFacilities'][$l++] = unserialize($row1[$i++]['venueIDFacilities']);  for this its printing oustside of venue array please have look i need to get this parameters insde venues array

Answer (score 1):

You need to try this solution.

```
            $sql1="select * from en_venues where providerID = $providerID ";
            $result1 = mysqli_query($con,$sql1) or die("Error in Selecting " . mysqli_error($connection));
            while ($row1['venue'][] = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result1)){

            $venueID=$row1['venue']['venueID'];
            $resultArray['venues'] = $row1; 

            $sql2 = "select * from en_schedules as e ,en_persons as p where e.venueID = '".$venueID."'";
            $result2 = mysqli_query($con,$sql2) or die("Error in Selecting " . mysqli_error($con));
            while ($row2['Persons'][] = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2)){
                $resultArray['Persons'] = $row2; 
            }
```

You can make array how you make it for persons.

Comment: copy pasted my question bro @saurabh

Comment: I have updated code at vanue. You need to check your query result with this.You have not provided your vanue array here. @saiibitta

Comment: getting error like <b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: venueID

Comment: Try to print print_r($row1); inside while loop. After that check your key and change value for $row1['venue']['venueID'] using key index.

Comment: Its printing duplicate array values like 1 1,2 1,2,3